# ZendFramework - How to use formSelect() view helper not to use auto "multiple"?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to use this select without `multiple` but its always list all country vertically. How to remove the auto multiple option without using external CSS?

```
    <?=$this->formSelect("Country", '', array(
                 'class'=>'Country',
                 'size' => 40,
                 'multiple'=>"multiple" // i removed this but still it auto applies
                ), $this->country);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Remove  `'size' => 40,` too. `SIZE` indicates how many rows of the list should be displayed.